# Blank screen for OS X App Review Team; working for everyone else

Tags: swift, macos

I'm currently dealing with a dilemma involving the OS X App Review Team. The screen is showing up, as it should, for myself, my team, as well as all of my beta testers:

[image: Screenshot]

However, the App Review Team came back with this:

```
2.3

The app does not achieve the core functionality described in your marketing materials or release notes.

The app launches with black window and no UI is loaded. Screenshot is attached for your reference.
```

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas? The application is a simple WebView. No idea why it would only not work for them.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit
import Foundation

let secureURL = "https://www.arcsoft.io/"

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var windowTitle: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var networkError: NSImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var retryButton: NSButton!

    @IBAction func attemptReload(sender: NSButton) {
        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: secureURL)!))
    }

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Initial WebView Setup
        webView.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = true
        WebPreferences.standardPreferences().allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true

        // Client Identifier
        let userAgent = "ARCSOFT Client v1.0"
        webView.customUserAgent = userAgent
        defaults.registerDefaults(["UserAgent": userAgent])
        defaults.registerDefaults(["User-Agent": userAgent])

        // Launch Secure Client
        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: secureURL)!))

        // Hide Network Error on Launch
        retryButton.hidden = true
        networkError.hidden = true
    }

    func webView(sender: WebView!, didReceiveTitle title: String!, forFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
        windowTitle.stringValue = "ARCSOFT™ – Web Builder & Design"
    }

    func webView(sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
        print("Load Successful")
        retryButton.hidden = true
        networkError.hidden = true
    }

    func webView(sender: WebView!, didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
        retryButton.hidden = true
        networkError.hidden = true
    }

    func webView(sender: WebView!, didFailProvisionalLoadWithError error: NSError!, forFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
        print("Failed to Load Client")
        // Present user with error.
        retryButton.hidden = false
        networkError.hidden = false
        networkError.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(red:0.145, green:0.145, blue:0.157, alpha:1.0).CGColor
    }

    func webView(sender: WebView!, runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener resultListener: WebOpenPanelResultListener!, allowMultipleFiles: Bool) {
        let openDialog = NSOpenPanel()
        if (openDialog.runModal() == NSModalResponseOK) {
            let fileName: String = (openDialog.URL?.path)!
            resultListener.chooseFilename(fileName) // Use chooseFilenames for multiple files
        }
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

**WindowViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa

class WindowViewController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        window!.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        window!.movableByWindowBackground  = true
        window!.title = ""
        window!.backgroundColor = NSColor(red:0.11, green:0.16, blue:0.20, alpha:1.0)
    }

}
```

Comment: @DanielStorm being that not even a single UI element is appearing for specifically the App Review Team, but is showing for everyone else – didn't think it would be a coding issue. Nevertheless, code has been added.

Comment: Does it have the right entitlement to get on the Internet?

Comment: @ElTomato http://i.imgur.com/3VJQvRD.png

Answer (score 0):

When I go to https://www.arcsoft.io/ in Safari on a Mac, I also see the completely blank screen for a second or two before everything shows up. It's possible that your request is timing out (or the reviewer hasn't waited very long) before the rest of the UI shows up. Perhaps it takes a while for you, too, but because you're used to it, you don't notice it. Either way, your app should be more responsive, either by reducing the load time of the Web page, and/or by displaying *something* on the app while the Web page is loading.

Comment: If this were the problem, then why is the UI completely blank? Maybe the WebView is taking time to load; however, not even the `Label` that I set by default as "ARCSOFT™ – Website Builder & Design" is appearing. It is literally showing a blank window with no UI elements. Furthermore, I have included code if the WebView does not load as expected. This can be seen in the ViewController.swift code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that your code should be implementing in order to work correctly. A proper `delegate` needs to be involved (the code in your example is currently relying entirely upon your `webView` to load before displaying anything). The reason someone sees a completely blank screen is because if there is no internet connection an empty `webView` is loaded. Also, since you haven't included `WebFrameLoadDelegate` the methods defined do absolutely nothing.

Once you have that implemented into your ViewController then you can connect the `frameLoad` Outlet in IB to your `webView` and the methods should be able to properly handle things.

↳ [WebView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/)

Comment: I did as you said. Sent it to the App Review Team, got rejected again for having a blank UI.

Comment: How are you testing your app? I would suggest unplugging your internet to see what actually happens. Please edit your question and include the updated code you tried.